# Fallo de login de SQLite3 en php 7.1.7 con Adminer

Tags: php, sqlite3, adminer

No sé cómo resolver este error que me aparece al tratar de iniciar el Login de SQLite3 con Adminer. Ya busqué y me sale un código (que pongo lineas abajo) para implementarlo y que pueda loguear pero me salen otros errores (el de compatibilidad). ¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?
Gracias

Este es el error que aparece:

> Implement login() method to use SQLite.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le coloco el código incluido en un index y me sale que debe ser compatible con Adminer:

> Warning: Declaration of AdminerSoftware::permanentLogin() should be compatible with Adminer::permanentLogin($i = false) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\sqlite\index.php on line 4

Éste es el código:

```
<?php
function adminer_object() {

    class AdminerSoftware extends Adminer {

        function name() {
            // custom name in title and heading
            return 'db';
        }

        function permanentLogin() {
            // key used for permanent login
            return "5f504fe1fdd79083c5435740d1d5263b";
        }

        function credentials() {
            // server, username and password for connecting to database
            return array('people.sqlite', '', '');
        }

        function database() {
            // database name, will be escaped by Adminer
            return 'cbm_people';
        }

        function login($login, $password) {
            // validate user submitted credentials
            return ($login == 'admin' && $password == 'test');
        }

        function tableName($tableStatus) {
            // tables without comments would return empty string and will be ignored by Adminer
            //return h($tableStatus["cbm_people"]);
        }

        function fieldName($field, $order = 0) {
            // only columns with comments will be displayed and only the first five in select
            //return ($order <= 5 && !ereg('_(md5|sha1)$', $field["field"]) ? h($field["comment"]) : "");
        }

    }

    return new AdminerSoftware;
}
include "../sqlite/editor.php";
?>
```

Esta imagen muestra cómo se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero con ese codigo tampoco te has podido loguiar?. intenta cambiar el include `include "../sqlite/editor.php";` por `include "adminer.php";` y me comentas que sucede.

Comment: hola pues mira me sale ahora este error:
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare connection() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\sqlite\adminer.php:15)

Comment: quitando el include que lo veo algo innecesario me sale este mensaje que debe ser compatible:
> Warning: Declaration of AdminerSoftware::permanentLogin() should be compatible with Adminer::permanentLogin($i = false) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\sqlite\index.php on line 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto que te quita el mensaje de warning de la pantalla, cambia esto:

```
function permanentLogin() {
    // key used for permanent login
    return "5f504fe1fdd79083c5435740d1d5263b";
}
```

por esto:

```
 function permanentLogin($i=false) {
        // key used for permanent login
        return "5f504fe1fdd79083c5435740d1d5263b";
    }
```

Es solo agregar el parametro a la funcion `$i=false`.
Parece que con la version de **php 7.1.7** el metodo tiene que tener el paramtro `$i=false` que con otras versiones inferiores de **php** no importa.Espero te ayude.

Comment: Buenas sirvió para el mensaje de error que salia pero ahora me dice que:
> Usuario y/o clave de acceso incorrecta.<
no se porque me sale esto si no puse nada de datos solo quiero crear una base de datos en blanco. Gracias

Comment: estas poniendo bien usuario y contraseña tiene que ser las que esten definidad aqui:` function login($login, $password) {
            // validate user submitted credentials
            return ($login == 'admin' && $password == 'test');
        }`

Comment: gracias si tarde un ratito en darme cuenta borre los campos y ahora me deja ponerlo sin ningún dato solo seleccionando SQLite3; pero ahora tengo otro problema el cual me dice que no tengo privilegios para añadir registros a la tabla que creo cualquiera que esta sea...